# How can I visually find out which programs are running on the current virtual screen in Unity?

Tags: unity, launcher

Since switching to Unity in 11.04 I miss the bottom only for one thing: I want to know which windows are on the current virtual screen. I switch between windows with alt+tab and sometimes I don't remember if the program I need is running on the current screen.

In the launcher there are white dots that shows running programs. But they show this for all virtual screens and this is not what I need.

Is there a way for example to setup launcher so it shows white dots only for current virtual screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there's a combination Shift+Alt+Up that will show you all windows from current desktop (unlike Win+w that will show you windows from all desktops).

You can see that (or change that) in CompizConfig manager (Expo plugin).

Comment: Wow! Thank you this is the thing I was looking for. It's hard to say, but I hope this hotkey will solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Ubuntu 14.04 there is a visual sign, that an app is running on the current screen or another:

applications on another workspace only have a thin arrow on it (in my example screenshot the console), on the current screen the arrow is filled and the current app has a second arrow from the right:

[image]

Comment: If someone knows, when this behaviour was introduced, feel free to edit my answer